# AWS SES - VPC Endpoint - does not send emails

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I have got an application hosted on `ec2` instance in private subnet where no internect connection is established. However, I want to send emails from this instance. So I decided to use `VPC Endpoint`.

Here is the `security group` of the vpc endpoint I created
[image]

`Source` is the private ip of my ec2 instance.

When I invoke the following command:

```
telnet email-smtp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com 587
```

The connnection is established because I got the response

```
Connected to email-smtp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com.
```

but when I try to send an email from my java application, I got the exception

```
amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: 
Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to email.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com:443 
[email.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/<SOME_IP>, 
email.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/<SOME_IP>,
email.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/<SOME_IP>, 
email.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/<SOME_IP>, 
email.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/<SOME_IP>, 
email.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/<SOME_IP>] failed: 
Connect timed out
```

the method I use to send emails

```kotlin
fun sendEmail() {
        val url = "url"
        val destination = Destination.builder().toAddresses(email).build()
        val subject = Content.builder().data("Suybject").build()
        val sesBody = Body.builder().text(Content.builder().data(data(url)).build()).build()
        val msg = Message.builder().subject(subject).body(sesBody).build()

        sesClient.sendEmail(
            SendEmailRequest.builder()
                .destination(destination)
                .message(msg)
                .source("email@domain.pl")
                .build()
        )
    }
```

and the `sesClient` config

```kotlin
  @Bean
    fun sesClient(): SesClient {
        val basicAWSCredentials = AwsBasicCredentials.create(sesAccessKey, sesSecretKey)
        val credentialsProvider = StaticCredentialsProvider.create(basicAWSCredentials)

        return SesClient
            .builder()
            .credentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
            .region(Region.EU_CENTRAL_1)
            .build()
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The SDK tries to connect through HTTP API of SES. The error log message says it tries to connect through 443 port, which is encrypted HTTP.

Your security group for this endpoint does not allow connections on 443 port. Please open it and retry the connection.

Comment: I opened the 443 port in inbound rules of vpc endpoint security group and got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I solved the problem. I stopped using `aws ses sdk`, because it tries to connect through HTTPS, while I need to connect through SMTP on 587 port.
So here is my final configuration

```
spring:
  mail:
    host: email-smtp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
    username: ${AWS_SES_USERNAME}
    password: ${AWS_SES_PASSWORD}
    port: 587
    protocol: smtp
    properties:
      mail.smtp.auth: true
      mail.smtp.starttls.enable: true
      mail.smtp.starttls.required: true
      mail.smtp.ssl.trust: email-smtp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
    test-connection: false
```

To generate `AWS_SES_USERNAME` and `AWS_SES_PASSWORD` you need to sign in into aws console, go to `Amazon SES` -> `SMTP Settings` -> `Create my SMTP credentials`

and the email is sent like this

```kotlin
        val message = mailSender.createMimeMessage()
        val helper = MimeMessageHelper(message, true)
        val body = data(url)

        helper.setFrom("your_verified_ses_email@domain.com")
        helper.setTo(destination)
        helper.setSubject("Subject")
        helper.setText(body)

        mailSender.send(message)
```